# angularjs bootstrap ui 0.13 datetimepicker doesn't pop up

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use https://github.com/zhaber/datetimepicker in my angular application but somehow datepicker doesn't pop up when input is clicked.
Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FTwLPJiwxBC8eEHxJiT0?p=preview and the controller's content (rest you can find in plunkr):

```
$scope.initDate = function(){
  $scope.date = new Date();
}

$scope.initDate();
```

Note: If I use 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js' then popup does work, but I need 0.13.0

Comment: check original example of Datepicker on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular UI 0.13 Requires AngularJs 1.3.x or above, and make sure you use the latest version of the widget: https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker